# Swift: Unable to get array values from singleton class

Tags: swift, ios8, singleton

Hi I retrived value from JSON and stored in NSMutableArray. I have tried this like Singleton. I have used empty swift file for this. Datas successfully retrieved and stored in NSMutableArray which is already declared in mainViewController. Then, if I use that NSMutableArray value in mainViewController, it shows empty array.

My coding is below. Kindly guide me.

**Empty Swift File**

```
 public class json_file{
    var prod_Obj = product_mainVC()

    class var shared: json_file
    {
        struct Static
        {
            static let instance: json_file = json_file()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func dataFromJSON()
    {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://........--...4900a20659")!
        var data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped, error: nil)!
        var dict: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        let dataArray = dict["data"] as [[String:AnyObject]]  // The array of dictionaries

        for object in dataArray {
            let category_name = object["category_name"] as String
            prod_Obj.ct_name_arr.addObject(category_name)

            let category_child = object["category_child"] as [[String:AnyObject]]
            for child in category_child {
                let sub_category_name = child["sub_category_name"] as String
                prod_Obj.sub_ct_name_arr.addObject(sub_category_name)
            }
        }

        println(prod_Obj.ct_name_arr) //Here value is Getting
        println(prod_Obj.sub_ct_name_arr) //Here value is Getting
    }

}
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
{
  json_file.shared.dataFromJSON()
  println(ct_name_arr) //Prints Empty Array  [Intially Declared as NSMutableArray]
  println(sub_ct_name_arr) //Prints Empty Array [Intially Declared as NSMutableArray]
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to swift myself, but it looks like you've embedded  a class within a class (which i dont think you can do) and also its difficult to debug as we dont know what `product_mainVC()` is?

Comment: Is dataArray empty? Print it out as soon as you have initalised it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying understand the problem, but I can't see the `product_mainVC`. Because this I remake your class with little modifications.

```
class JsonFile
{
    private(set) var categoryNames:[String];
    private(set) var subCategoryNames:[String];

    class let shared:JsonFile = JsonFile();

    private init()
    {
        self.categoryNames = [];
        self.subCategoryNames = [];
    }

    func dataFromJson()
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://........--...4900a20659")!
        if let data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped, error: nil)
        {
            if let dict: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let dataArray = dict["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]  // The array of dictionaries
                {
                    for object in dataArray {
                        let category_id = object["category_id"] as Int
                        let category_name = object["category_name"] as String
                        categoryNames.append(category_name);


                        let category_child = object["category_child"] as [[String:AnyObject]]
                        for child in category_child {
                            let sub_category_id = child["sub_category_id"] as Int
                            let sub_category_name = child["sub_category_name"] as String
                            subCategoryNames.append(sub_category_name);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        println(categoryNames);
        println(subCategoryNames);
    }
}
```

### I did

Modify your way to do `Singleton` to a safe and more simple mode, create the arrays `categoryNames` and `subCategoryNames` internal in class because this is better to manipulate, and protect your fetch data to safe from possibles crash.

### Implementation

```
JsonFile.shared.dataFromJson();

println("count categoryNames");
println(JsonFile.shared.categoryNames.count);
println("count subCategoryNames");
println(JsonFile.shared.subCategoryNames.count);
```

### You need think about

This code is sync, and because this if you have a big data or request slow, the main thread from your application will freeze waiting return and it is bad for your user. Think if is necessary be sync.

`let category_id = object["category_id"] as Int` is never used. Why do you stay with this in code?

Comment: This datas are retrieved once. That is home screen datas and side menu. So sync may be fine.